# Estimate for L1 funcction

Tags: fourier-analysis, exponential-function, special-functions, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Suppose  for every $r\in \mathbb{R}$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert f(x)\rvert e^{rx}dx<\infty$. Then is it true that there exists $C>0$ and $\alpha>1$, such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq Ce^{\lvert x\rvert^{-\alpha}}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: almost everywhere?

Comment: and what is the point of having $r$ and $a$?

Comment: yes almost everywhere.

Comment: $a$ is fixed, and the integral is finite for each real $r$

Comment: we may ignore $a$

Comment: If r is fixed then the statement is not true, unbounded $L^1$ function would be a counter example. But I need for every $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counter-example**

Let us consider a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, such that for every $n \in \mathbb Z$, $f(x)=e^n$ on $[n, n+c_n]$, with $c_n>0$.

Let $r \in \mathbb R_{-}$, then $$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| e^{rx} \mathrm{d}x \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n e^{(r+1)n}$$ The last sum converges if $c_n$ = $e^{-n^2}$ for example.

Let $r \in \mathbb R_{+}$, then $$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| e^{rx} \mathrm{d}x \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n e^{r(n+1) + rc_n}$$ And the sum still converges.

Comment: +1, thanks!! why $rc_n$ is added in the last inequality? Is the first inequality not working for positive $r$. since $\int e^{-x^2+ax}$ is finite independent of $a$, I think first inequality will work for both positive and negative $r$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @partha the $x$ that matter (the ones for which $f(x) \neq 0$) are such that $n \leq x \leq n+c_n$. When you multiply by $r$ the equalities change if $r<0$, which is why you have to distinguish two cases

Comment: got it, I was missing that part

Comment: The function $f$ in your example also satisfies $\leq C e^{|x|^{-\alpha}}$, right?

Comment: woops @ntt you are perfectly correct, I edited my function $f$

Comment: If there exists $C>0$ and $\alpha>1$ such that $1\leq Ce^{\lvert x\rvert^{-\alpha}}$ then $e^{\rvert x\lvert^{\alpha}}\leq C$ but $e^{\lvert x\rvert ^\alpha}$ is unbounded.

Comment: @partha, no because $1/e^{|x|^{-\alpha}}=e^{-|x|^{-\alpha}} \neq e^{|x|^{\alpha}}$

Comment: @fonfox I am very sorry for all my blunder. I was looking for function $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq Ce^{-\lvert x\rvert^\alpha}$. So I think your first example will work. And that was a bounded function. thank you very much.

Comment: @partha it is actually what I thought first, but my new function works for both cases :)